# Receiving larger bytebuffer Android

Tags: netty, packet, bytebuffer

I'm using the framework Netty with Android and having problems when I receive large amounts of data:

```
@Override public void channelRead(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
    bufferIn = (ByteBuf) msg;
    if (bufferIn.readableBytes() >= 4) { 
        size   = bufferIn.readInt();
        result = bufferIn.toString(CharsetUtil.ISO_8859_1);
        if(size == result.length){
           Log.d("D", "RECEIVED: " + size + " " + result);
        }
        ctx.flush();
    }
    bufferIn.release();
```

}

When I receive the data it comes in packets, and I'm not knowing how to receive that parcels.
Thanks

I add the line:

```
ch.pipeline().addLast(new NettyDecoder(), new NettyHandler(service, size, message, listener));
```

On the decoder:

```
class NettyDecoder extends ByteToMessageDecoder

@Override protected void decode(final ChannelHandlerContext theContext, final ByteBuf in, List<Object> out) throws Exception {
    if (in.readableBytes() < 4) {
        return;
    }
    in.markReaderIndex();
    int dataLength = in.readInt();
    if (in.readableBytes() < dataLength) {
        in.resetReaderIndex();
        return;
    }
    byte[] decoded = new byte[dataLength];
    in.readBytes(decoded);
    out.add(decoded);
    //out.add(in.readBytes(in.readableBytes()));
}
```

On the handler:

```
void channelRead(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
    ByteBuf m = (ByteBuf) msg;
    bufferIn.writeBytes(m); 
    m.release();
    if (bufferIn.readableBytes() >= 4) { 
        size   = bufferIn.readInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < bufferIn.capacity(); i ++) {
            byte b = bufferIn.getByte(i);
        result += (char) b;
        }
    }
    Log.d("WEB", "RESULT: " + size + " " + result.getBytes().length + " " + result);
        bufferIn.release();
```

But now I don't receive any message on the NettyHandler.

Can someone teachs me how to receive the messages on the handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to extend ByteToMessageDecoder and let it do the job of aggregation of needed. See the javadocs of it for more details.

Comment: Ok Norman, I'll look for that, do you know where can I find a example?

Comment: There are many codecs that use it within netty... Just check the codec module.